# How multi sampling works for Integer textures

Tags: opengl, multisampling

I didn't find any documentation on how Integer texture should behave for Multisampling.

For example, for 4 sub-samples, if the values in sub-samples are 0, 0, 500, 500.
Does it resolve to 250,250,250,250?

Answer (score 2):

When applied to integer framebuffer attachments, a multisample resolve operation (as caused by `glBlitFramebuffer`) simply selects a single sample from within the pixel to represent the entire value. Which sample is selected is not specified, so it's up to the implementation.

Basically, there's no real useful purpose to resolving an integer multisample attachment. If you have some multisample integer buffer (such as with deferred rendering), the only useful resolve you're going to get is one you write yourself.

Comment: I attach integer texture as MRT and I really don't want my texture to be multisampled but as the default color buffer is MSAA, so is my integer texture, I am worried as I store uniform in integer textures and I don't want my values to be interpolated. Is it guaranteed to get the same value as uniform when I read back integer texture in the case of Multisampling?

Comment: If the value really is "uniform" and unchanging... why are you storing it in a texture? That's a waste of good memory bandwidth. If the value is *different* in different places, then it's not "uniform" even if the source of each pixel was a shader `uniform` variable. And in that case, what I said above applies: you'll get *one* of the values in that pixel. Which one is unknowable, so it's probably not useful. What does this image represent, and why can't you just read the multisampled data?

Comment: I assign a unique ID to each and every object in the scene, I push that ID as uniform to draw call. I store the ID in texture which is common to all draws. I read back that ID texture and do the post-process. It's a part of a big project. I just want to ensure that even with MSAA, my IDs should not be interpolated, if it picks any of the subsamples, it's fine.